# Como fazer parse em Json Android

Tags: java, android, json, parse

Preciso de fazer o parse para o seguinte json

```
{
    "rssEmpregados": {
        "pesquisa": "marcia",
        "registoInicial": "0",
        "ordem": "ASC",
        "parametrosList": [
            {
                "parametros": [],
                "tabela": "EMPREGADOS_CRSS",
                "coluna1": "CODIGO_CRSS",
                "coluna2": "DESCRICAO",
                "coluna": "CODIGO_CRSS"
            },
            {
                "parametros": [],
                "tabela": "EMPREGADOS_FORMAS_PAGAMENTO",
                "coluna1": "CODIGO_FORMA_PAGAMENTO",
                "coluna2": "DESCRICAO",
                "coluna": "CODIGO_FORMA_PAGAMENTO"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Ja tenho fiz o codigo para a parte inicial, mas estou com dificuldades com o resto.

```
try {
    JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject rssEmpregados = new JSONObject();
    rssEmpregados.put("pesquisa", procuraTextoEt.getText());
    rssEmpregados.put("registoInicial", "0");
    rssEmpregados.put("ordem", "ASC");
    js.put("rssEmpregados", rssEmpregados);
    Log.e("params", rssEmpregados.toString());

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de mais umas pesquisas consegui o que queria, deixo aqui para no futuro alguém que precise.

```
try {
           JSONArray parametrosList = new JSONArray();
           JSONObject rssEmpregados = new JSONObject();
           rssEmpregados.put("pesquisa", procuraTextoEt.getText());
           rssEmpregados.put("registoInicial", "0");
           rssEmpregados.put("ordem", "ASC");
           rssEmpregados.put("parametrosList", parametrosList);
           js.put("rssEmpregados", rssEmpregados);

           JSONObject codigoEstabelecimento = new JSONObject();
           codigoEstabelecimento.put("parametros", "[]");
           codigoEstabelecimento.put("tabela", "ESTABELECIMENTOS");
           codigoEstabelecimento.put("coluna1", "CODIGO_ESTABELECIMENTO");
           codigoEstabelecimento.put("coluna2", "DESCRICAO");
           codigoEstabelecimento.put("coluna", "CODIGO_ESTABELECIMENTO");
           parametrosList.put(codigoEstabelecimento);


           JSONObject codigoSituacao = new JSONObject();
           codigoSituacao.put("parametros", "[]");
           codigoSituacao.put("tabela", "EMPREGADOS_SIT_PROFISSIONAIS");
           codigoSituacao.put("coluna1", "CODIGO_SITUACAO");
           codigoSituacao.put("coluna2", "DESCRICAO");
           codigoSituacao.put("coluna", "CODIGO_SITUACAO");
           parametrosList.put(codigoSituacao);
```

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Coloque tudo dentro de um JSONARRAY. Segue um exemplo:

```
try {
                        JSONArray jsArr = new JSONArray();
                        JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
                        JSONObject rssEmpregados = new JSONObject();
                        rssEmpregados.put("pesquisa", procuraTextoEt.getText());
                        rssEmpregados.put("registoInicial", "0");
                        rssEmpregados.put("ordem", "ASC");
                        js.put("rssEmpregados", rssEmpregados);
                        jsArr.put(js);
                        js = new JSONObject();
                        Log.e("params", rssEmpregados.toString());

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Esse codigo vai montar um array para 1 item json, para colocar mais é so meter um laço ali no meio (for ou while)

Answer (score 1):

Cara, começa pela identação da sua formatação Json. Acho que assim fica mais facil de ler a estrutura do objeto que você vai precisar

```
{ 
    "rssEmpregados": 
    { 
        "pesquisa":"marcia", 
        "registoInicial":"0", 
        "ordem":"ASC",  
        "parametrosList" :[ 
            {
                "parametros":[],
                "tabela" : "EMPREGADOS_CRSS",
                "coluna1" : "CODIGO_CRSS",
                "coluna2" : "DESCRICAO",
                "coluna" : "CODIGO_CRSS"
            },
            {
                "parametros":[],
                "tabela" : "EMPREGADOS_FORMAS_PAGAMENTO",
                "coluna1" : "CODIGO_FORMA_PAGAMENTO",
                "coluna2" : "DESCRICAO",
                "coluna" : "CODIGO_FORMA_PAGAMENTO"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

A partir deste ponto você começa a montar suas propriedades. 
Precisa ficar atento apenas ao Arrays, como por exemplo em "parametrosList". Ali você vai precisar passar um JSONArray, que possui vários JSONObject.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o `GSON`.

Monte um objeto exatamente na estrutura que precisa com `implements Serializable`

Os sub-itens com ocorrencia de lista devem estar dentro de Arrays exemplo: `ArrayLists<parametrosList>`...

Ai você converte facilmente com:

```
gson.toJson(objetoX); //retorna um json em string

objeto= gson.fromJson("seu json aqui", ObjetoX.class); //retorna um objeto
```